# Using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles vs Marshal.AllocHGlobal and Marshal.FreeHGlobal

Tags: .net, winapi, marshalling

I have a .Net class that allocates unmanaged memory for a `struct` using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` and then disposes of it using `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`.

I understand that the classes `Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles` provide wrappers that handle this, but it isn't clear how to instantiate them (many don't have constructors) - should I be writing a specific implementation of the abstract base class or is there some way to use them in the `extern` declaration?

Comment: The main problem of subclassing `SafeHandle` is that to `Marshal.DestroyStructure` you need the `Type` of the `struct`... This makes everything more complex. You can't use generics (beause they aren't compatible with pinvoke)... So you can have multiple `SafeHandle` subclasses (one for each `Type`), or a property inside the `SafeHandle` with the type of the `struct` that you set manually... Or you can make the constructor of the `SafeHandle` accept the `struct` to be marshaled and set the `Type` inside a property.

Comment: I think SafeHandle is wrapper for HANDLE (user mode identifier of kernel object) and AllocHGlobal, FreeHGlobal are methods for manipulating by unmanaged memory buffers. Do you really want to mix the notions?

Comment: @SerG from managed code? Sure - I want to allocate something in memory, get the handle for it and do something with that, then deallocate and make sure that memory is freed. Typically this means lots of `try-finally` blocks, but that isn't always practical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem of subclassing `SafeHandle` is that to `Marshal.DestroyStructure` you need the `Type` of the struct... This makes everything more complex.

You can't use generics (because they aren't compatible with pinvoke)... So you can have multiple `SafeHandle` subclasses (one for each `Type`), or a property inside the `SafeHandle` with the type of the struct that you set manually... Or you can make the constructor of the `SafeHandle` accept the struct to be marshaled and set the `Type` inside a property.

I'm using the last two "options" (property `Type` that can be set manually or that can be set automatically by a constructor)

Example of `MySafeHandle`:

```
public class MySafeHandle : SafeHandle
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    public MySafeHandle() : base(IntPtr.Zero, true)
    {
    }

    public MySafeHandle(object obj)
        : base(IntPtr.Zero, true)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            Type = obj.GetType();
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);

            try
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                // the finally part can't be interrupted by
                // Thread.Abort
                handle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, handle, false);
            }
        }
    }

    public override bool IsInvalid
    {
        get { return handle == IntPtr.Zero; }
    }

    [SecurityCritical]
    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            if (Type == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            try
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.DestroyStructure(handle, Type);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(handle);
                handle = IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The constructor you should use is the one that marshals the structure with `Marshal.StructureToPtr`. It has the advantage that it saves the type of the structure so that it can use it later to `Marshal.DestroyStructure`.

Comment: Cheers, very detailed answer with what I wanted to know :-)

Comment: @Keith Note that I've moved the `Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, handle, false);` inside the `finally {}` block... It isn't showed in the history of the psot because I've done in the first 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented this as a generic with a type constraint - `class SafeStructHandle<T> : SafeHandle where T : struct`

Comment: Yeah, but the generic isn't passed to any of the `Marshal` or pInvoke methods - it's just used on the handle wrapper class. `object.GetType` gets replaced with `typeof(T)` with the advantage of limiting it to `struct` objects at compile time. Why is that still a problem? Am I missing something about how this should be called?

Comment: @Keith No... if you don't need to use it directly with PInvoke then there is no problem. And even if you want to pass it to a PInvoke method, if you want to pass it as an "in" parameter (so something created C# side), you can probably pass it as a `SafeHandle someParameter` (not tested)

Comment: I've tested it now - I can use `SafeHandle` as the parameter on an `extern` call (instead of the `IntPtr` for the allocation) but pass in the generic `SafeStructHandle<T>` to be implicitly cast.